# Intersection of two perpendicular tangent planes to the paraboloid $x^2 + y^2 = 2z$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, 3d

Two perpendicular tangent planes to the paraboloid

**$x^2 + y^2 = 2z $**

intersect in a straight line in the plane **$ x = 0$**

Obtain the curve to which this straight line touches.

I tried this by forming equations of planes

$ l_1x + m_1y +n_1z = -(l_1^2 + m_1^2)/2n_1 $

$ l_2x + m_2y +n_2z = -(l_2^2 + m_2^2)/2n_2 $

But I couldn't proceed further.

Comment: "Obtain the curve to which this straight line touches". The number of curves this line touches is uncountably infinite. Maybe you could give some additional criteria this curve should also satisfy?

Comment: This is the exact question provided in the book.

Comment: Were you able to find the equation of line?

Answer (score 2):

The paraboloid can be parametrized by $$(u,v) \mapsto r =\left(u, v, \frac{u^2+v^2}2\right)$$
So $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} = (1, 0, u)\\\frac{\partial r}{\partial v} = (0, 1, v)$$
are two tangent vectors in the tangent plane. Their cross product $(u,v,-1)$ is therefore orthogonal to the tangent plane. For the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ on the paraboloid, $u = x_0, v = y_0$, so the plane normal is $(x_0, y_0, -1)$. Since the point must be on the plane, the plane equation is $$(x_0, y_0, -1)\cdot (x, y, z) = (x_0, y_0, -1)\cdot(x_0,y_0,z_0)$$
which expands to $$x_0x + y_0y - z = x_0^2 + y_0^2 - z_0$$
or $$x_0x + y_0y - z = z_0$$
since $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = 2z_0$.

This tangent plane intersects the plane $x = 0$ in the line $y_0y = z + z_0$. The tangent plane at a second point $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ intersects in the line $y_1y = z+z_1$. These two equations can only be equations of the same line if $y_1 = y_0$ and $z_1 = z_0$. (From the equation for the paraboloid it follows that $x_1 = \pm x_0$, and since the points need to be distinct, we have $x_1 = -x_0$.)

So the points of tangency must be $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $(-x_0, y_0, z_0)$, where $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = 2z_0^2$, and the line of intersection must be $$x = 0;\quad z = y_0y - z_0$$

And as I've already mentioned, this line "touches" infinitely many curves, so I have no idea what curve they are after.